# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable al imprimir arreglo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy haciendo un programa que debe ordenar los dígitos de una lista y luego mostrar cual es el mayor.

**Mi código es :**

```
print("bienvenido \n ")

arreglo = [1, 5, 7, 0, 6, -100, 20]
largo = len(arreglo)
i = 0

while (i < largo):    
    j = i

    while (j < largo):    
        if (arreglo[i] > arreglo[j]):   
            aux = arreglo[i]    
            arreglo[i] = arreglo[j]    
            arreglo[j] = aux    
        j = j + 1    
    i = i + 1

for arreglo in arreglo:    
    print(arreglo)

print ("El numero mayor es : ", arreglo[6])
```

Estoy con Pycharn y en la última línea no me tira error, pero al ejecutarlo si:

```
bienvenido 

-100    
0    
1    
5    
6    
7    
20

Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "C:/Users/Dennis Andino/PycharmProjects/Ejemplos_basicos/ordenamiento_numeros.py", line 19, in <module>    
    print ("El numero mayor es : ", arreglo[6])    
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable    

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Ya probé asignando el valor en una variable o convirtiendo el valor en string pero igualmente me da el mismo error.

Estoy en Python 3.6

Comment: muchas Gracias FJSevilla , eres el puto amo.    me has ayudado mucho.   Soy nuevo en stack no sé si se puede dar puntos sino te doy los 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código en general es correcto, el error en realidad es muy simple:

```
for arreglo in arreglo:    
    print(arreglo)

print ("El numero mayor es : ", arreglo[6])
```

Haces `for arreglo in arreglo`, esto ocasiona que al final `arreglo` no sea la lista sino el último elemento de ella obtenido en el `for`, un entero, de ahí el error. Al hacer posteriormente `arreglo[6]` lo que haces en realidad es `20[6]`. Debes cambiar la variable del `for` a algo que no sea el nombre del iterable, por ejemplo: `for n in arreglo`.

Por otro lado, para imprimir el número mayor, como tienes la lista ordenada, basta con imprimir el último índice. Python permite usar índices negativos, si usas `arreglo[-1]` te imprime el último elemento de la lista, tenga ésta el tamaño que tenga.

El código quedaría así:

```
print("bienvenido \n ")

arreglo = [1, 5, 7, 0, 6, -100, 20]
largo = len(arreglo)
i = 0

while (i < largo):    
    j = i
    while (j < largo):    
        if (arreglo[i] > arreglo[j]):   
            aux = arreglo[i]    
            arreglo[i] = arreglo[j]    
            arreglo[j] = aux    
        j = j + 1   
    i = i + 1

for n in arreglo:    
    print(n)

print ("El numero mayor es : ", arreglo[-1])
```

Comment: muchas Gracias FJSevilla , eres el puto amo. me has ayudado mucho. Soy nuevo en stack no sé si se puede dar puntos sino te doy los 10.